# Testing built in $filter functions in OData with ASP.nET Core and Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, odata

I am trying to test some built in collection `$filter` functions in OData with ASP.NET Core and Entity Framework.

Specifically, I am looking at hassubset (but hassubsequences gives the same issues) http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.01/odata-v4.01-part1-protocol.html#sec_BuiltinQueryFunctions

I am running the following odata query: `http://localhost/comments?$filter=Id%20eq%20'1234'%20and%20hassubset(CommentWords%2C%20%5B'hello'%5D)`
The filter part unencoded is `$filter=Id eq '1234' and hassubset(CommentWords, ['hello'])`

I am getting the following error:

> The query specified in the URI is not valid. An unknown function with name 'hassubset' was found. This may also be a function import or a key lookup on a navigation property, which is not allowed.

My question is: given my setup below, what can I change for the the OData query to work?

NOTE: My goal here is to probe the OData protocol and its collection functions. So, something like:

```
$filter=Id eq '1234' and contains(CommentText, 'hello')
```

will not solve my problem.

A simplified version of my setup is as follows

OData entity:

```cs
public class CommentEntity
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string CommentText { get; set; }

    public IQueryable<string> CommentWords => CommentText.Split(" ").AsQueryable();
}
```

Controller action to expose the entity:

```cs
[EnableQuery]
[HttpGet("comments")]
public IQueryable<CommentEntity> GetComments()
{
    return _dbContext.Comments.AsQueryable();
}
```

OData setup in `Program.cs`:

```cs
builder.Services
    .AddControllers()
    .AddOData(opt => 
    {
        var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
        builder.EntitySet<CommentEntity>(nameof(CommentEntity));
        
        opt
            .EnableQueryFeatures()
            .AddRouteComponents("service/odata", builder.GetEdmModel());
    });
```

Snippet of entity from `odata/$metadata`:

```xml
<EntityType Name="Comment">
    <Key>
        <PropertyRef Name="Id" />
    </Key>
    <Property Name="Id" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" />
    <Property Name="CommentTest" Type="Edm.String" />
    <Property Name="CommentWords" Type="Collection(Edm.String)" />
</EntityType>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer, this functionality is not supported yet. It is on the roadmap

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/odata/resources/roadmap